unable to connect flyway to snowflake using user and key pair authentication
I'm trying to migrate DB objects(tables, views, procedures, etc) from dev to other regions using flyway. I'm currently using flyway 10.15.2 version and trying to connect to snowflake via key pair authentication(public & pvt key). Below is my flyway.conf file and i'm getting the below error while running 'flyway -X info'
flyway.url=jdbc:snowflake://xb44352.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=ENT_MDM_RAW&warehouse=EDP_ENT_MDM_ANALYTICS_WH
flyway.user=KXXS361@ASTRAZENECA.NET
flyway.warehouse=EDP_ENT_MDM_ANALYTICS_WH
flyway.role=EDP_EDP_ENT_MDM_ANALYST_DEV
flyway.jdbcProperties.private_key_file=\Users\kxxs361\rsa_key.p8


C:\flyway\flyway-10.15.2>flyway -X info
DEBUG: Java Version: 17.0.11+9
DEBUG: Loading config file: C:\flyway\flyway-10.15.2\conf\flyway.conf
DEBUG: Loading config file: C:\Users\kxxs361\flyway.conf
DEBUG: Unable to load config file: C:\flyway\flyway-10.15.2\flyway.conf
DEBUG: Using configuration:
DEBUG: [environments.sample] ->
[flyway] ->
flyway.jdbcProperties.db -> ENT_MDM_RAW
flyway.jdbcProperties.jdbc_query_result_format -> json
flyway.jdbcProperties.private_key_file -> \Users\kxxs361\rsa_key.p8
flyway.jdbcProperties.role -> EDP_EDP_ENT_MDM_ANALYST_DEV
flyway.jdbcProperties.warehouse -> EDP_ENT_MDM_ANALYTICS_WH
flyway.locations -> filesystem:C:\flyway\flyway-10.15.2\sql
flyway.role -> EDP_EDP_ENT_MDM_ANALYST_DEV
flyway.url -> jdbc://app.eu-west-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com/
flyway.user -> KXXS361@ASTRAZENECA.NET
flyway.warehouse -> EDP_ENT_MDM_ANALYTICS_WH

ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc://app.eu-west-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com/
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:926)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:864)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.getDataSource(ClassicConfiguration.java:890)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configure(ClassicConfiguration.java:2487)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.configuration(FluentConfiguration.java:1671)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.configuration.LegacyConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(LegacyConfigurationManager.java:851)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.configuration.ConfigurationManagerImpl.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManagerImpl.java:811)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:874)
        flyway.jdbcProperties.private_key_file=\Users\kxxs361\rsa_key.p8


Hi - probably not a great idea to post your Snowflake URL and username (which also tells everyone which company you work for) on a public forum

Taken from https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/snowflake-184127607.html - You might need the authenticator=snowflake_jwt section in the JDBC URL
In addition to this, do you have --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED in your JAVA_ARGS?
